# How to merge two tables in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

First of sorry I know mysql is not recommended any more but in this case I have no control and have to use it.

Now onto the question.

I have two tables
`Games` and `videos`

Inside games I have

```
| id | gameID | GameTitle | 
| 1  | 1      | Halo ODST |
| 2  | 2      | Disgaea 4 |
```

Inside videos I have

```
| id | game | videoTitle | image |
| 1  | 1    | Title 1    | PATH  |
| 2  | 1    | Title 2    | PATH  |
| 3  | 2    | Title 3    | PATH  |
| 4  | 1    | Title 4    | PATH  |
```

I need to basically do the following

```
Select x,y,z from video where videos.game = games.gameID
```

which will basically read

```
select id, videoTitle, image from videos where video.game = 1
```

(or some other numeric value)

I’m aware I have to use a join however nothing I have tried appears to be working and yeah I’m getting nowhere with this.

The closest I am is the below query which says it works but is returning an empty result set so clearly its wrong somewhere.

```
SELECT * FROM `games` INNER JOIN `videos` on `game` WHERE `game` = 1
```

If its any help I'm using phpmyadmins sql query tool rather than actual code at this stage as i just want to get it working before coding it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post some sample data?

Comment: @Quassnoi i have updated the question let me know if that's what you are after thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `games` g
INNER JOIN
        `videos` v
ON      v.game = g.gameId
WHERE   g.gameId = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use view to merge table and can perform operations on that..

```
create view view_name as
select Games.id,gameID, GameTitle,videos.id, game, videoTitle, image 
from Games,videos
where videos.game = games.gameID
```

where section will contain ids or anything you want to match